# How to instantiate a List<List<Integer>>?

Tags: java

I encountered a problem while solving problems on LeetCode. The question has a form:

```
public List<List<Integer>> generate(){

}
```

that requires returning a `List<List<Integer>>`. I know for `List<T>` I can do a `LinkedList<T>` or `ArrayList<T>`. How can I instantiate it that the compiler would not complain? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

The outer list type needs to be a concrete type like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, but the inner list type should be `List`. On more recent Java versions, you can do

```
return new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: It's worth noticing that whenever you try to insert an element inside an inner list, you must make sure to add a new `ArrayList<Integer>` to the outer one before.

Comment: @Jack: Only if the list you're trying to add to isn't already there.

Answer (score 1):

`List<List<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();`

Then when you want to add stuff to it do

`List<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); myList.add(innerList);`